# Etymology of 'go dutch'

Tags: slang, food

So I just learned about the etymology of 'AA' from

[The origins of "AA制"](https://chinese.stackexchange.com/questions/1777/the-origins-of-aa%E5%88%B6)

I wonder if anyone has a similar response for the phrase 'go dutch'.

It is hard to believe this originated from the Netherlands, seeing that it is quite commonly used in Hong Kong and Mainland China.

I first heard it in a Mainland Chinese TV drama in the English subtitles.

Bonus points if anyone could provide me the traditional and simplified characters for 'go dutch'?

Comment: Are you asking about the etymology of the _English_ phrase "to dutch", or are you just repeating the other question? If the former, it's not really for this stackexchange. Presumably the etymology has to do with the ill-will between the British and the Dutch (where the English believed they were stingy bastards).

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it seems to be asking about the origins of an English phrase.

Comment: I can't find a question here---but it seems unrelated to the title.  It also seems like a duplicate of the linked question.

Comment: @Becky李蓓 No, it is not a duplicate. AA and Go dutch have a difference. young99 provided a correct answer

Answer (score 5, accepted):

《懶蟲簡明英漢詞典》

> go Dutch
>   verb
>   各人付自己的帳

Usually, we simply say 各付各的 or 各出各的 in both TC and SC.

[Others](https://tw.ichacha.net/go%20dutch.html):
    各付各的帳
    各付一半帳
    各付一半賬
    各付帳
    各人付自己的帳
    各人自付錢
    各人自己付錢
    各自付錢
    各自付帳
    各自負擔自己費用

According to the legend of the Anglo-Dutch scramble for colonies and competition for the international trade market, because of the frequent conflict and dislike of the two countries, such usage appeared in English, contrary to the "generous" image of an English gentleman.

Answer (score 2):

各付各的钱，自己付自己的，也会直接说AA。
know more about chinese slangs, you can check here :
http://www.hanbridgemandarin.com/article/daily-chinese-learning-tips/chinese-slang-words-you-must-know/

Answer (score 0):

Etymologically, the "AA" in "AA制" is come from "Algebraic Average".(There is no official verdict)

Other origins:

1. Acting Appointment
2. Late Latin "ana", from German, again

According to: http://baike.baidu.com/item/AA%E5%88%B6

Comment: In addition, www.baidu.com is Chinese Google, you can search what you want (in Chinese) on it.